# Deploying Angular 9 .NET Core template in IIS

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-core-angular

I'm trying to deploy .net core app with Angular, a project I created from the template available in Visual Studio.

The application I have in IIS is set to run from the angular app

[image]

Now within the same application, I added api application which is pointing to the api folder:

[image]

While I'm able to access the angular app, when I'm trying to login by calling the controller in the .net core application I'm getting this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The SPA default page middleware
>   could not return the default page '/index.html' because it was not
>   found, and no other middleware handled the request. Your application
>   is running in Production mode, so make sure it has been published, or
>   that you have built your SPA manually. Alternatively you may wish to
>   switch to the Development environment.

Previously, when I was working with angular and .net core I had one project in VS for the .net core app and one project for the angular app and they were running from different subdomains, for example app.mywebsite.com for the angular app and api.mywebsite.com for the .net core app and I didn't have issues.

I was hoping with the .net core / Angular template I'll be able to run both the app and the api from one project but I'm currently experiencing the issues I mentioned above.

Comment: There are many things that *could* be going wrong :(  Please read this thread, and post back what you find: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5223.  See also [Publishing .netcore angular project gives “The SPA default page middleware could not return index.html”, works in debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58746054/publishing-netcore-angular-project-gives-the-spa-default-page-middleware-could)

Comment: Thanks @FoggyDay I went through all the comments but nothing useful for me there. The issue is with the api part of the application and what is the best way to serve that part since the issue happens when I'm making some api request

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.